# How to parse an application/ipp HTTP Request using node.js

Tags: node.js, http, https

I have a local web server with an HTTP endpoint that will receive requests with application/ipp as content type.

The web server is implemented using node.js, and I have been using body-parser in extracting the request's body for quite some time, but this one is different since body-parser does not support application/ipp. Was searching for resources but to no luck, didn't find one.

Maybe anyone has an idea on how to parse the request's body with a content type of application/ipp?

Thanks.